# Showing a variable converges in probability

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

I have a random variable
$Y_n$ with probability density function $f_{Y_n}(y) = \frac{n}{\theta}\left(1- \frac{y}{\theta}\right)^{n-1}$ for $0 < y < \theta$ and $n$ is a positive integer.
To show $Y$ converges to $0$ in probability, I consider
$\mathbb{P}(|Y_n - 0| > \varepsilon)$ and show for large $n$, this equals to zero.
The thing is, how would I get rid of the absolute value sign?
For context, $Y_n$ is the minimum of $(X_k)$ for $k= 1,2,3,\cdots,n$ and $X_i$ follows the distribution $U(0,\theta)$.
The solution just simply took away the absolute value signs, but why?

Comment: "show for large n, this equals to zero" This is never zero, actually.

Comment: Please, go back to my answer which I had to edit.

Comment: Appreciate your answer @zoli. What does Did mean by it never being zero?

Comment: @Did meant that $\mathbb{P}(|Y_n - 0| > \varepsilon)>0$ for all $n$ and that it never gets $0$ even if it converges to zero.

Comment: My bad...? I was trying to refer to you, but it doesn't allow me to refer to more than one user in a comment, so I removed the @.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\theta\ge Y_n\ge 0$ so the absolute value sign can be removed.

**EDITED**

For any $\varepsilon>0$, the probability that $Y_n>\varepsilon$ can be calculated based on the pdf belonging to $Y_n$:
$$P(Y_n>\varepsilon)=\frac n{\theta}\int_{\varepsilon}^{\theta}\left(1-\frac{y}{\theta}\right)^{n-1}\ dy=-\left[\left(1-\frac{y}{\theta}\right)^{n}\right]_{\varepsilon}^{\theta}=\left(1-\frac{\varepsilon}{\theta}\right)^n.$$

For any $\theta$ ($\theta>\varepsilon$): $0<1-\frac {\varepsilon}{\theta}<1$. That is $\left(1-\frac{\varepsilon}{\theta}\right)^{n}$ tends to zero if $n$ tends to infinity. So does the probability on the left. This is convergence to zero in probability.